# Example of using RestSharp to create a Jira issue

Tags: rest, jira, restsharp

I wonder if anyone has used RestSharp against the4 Jira 5.0 REST API? I've looked at Atlassian's sample code, which just gives raw JSON. I can't figure out how to make RestSharp create requests in the right format.

I'm really new to RestSharp and REST in general, I just need an example to look at to give me that 'ah-ha' moment.

Anyone?

Comment: Here's my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380845/restsharp-post-request-translation-from-curl-request/39146711#39146711

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code for simple JiraRestClient using RestSharp - https://bitbucket.org/MikeJansen/jirarestclient.net/wiki/Home

And here is a good documentation on how to consume REST services
http://www.stum.de/2009/12/22/using-restsharp-to-consume-restful-web-services/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually quite useful. I'm having problems with Newtonsoft.Json at the moment, I get a VerificationException for even the simplest serialization operation, so I've decided to have a go with Hammock instead.

Comment: If you find it helpful why not accept an answer? In regards to VerificationException have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968084/json-net-verificationexception-operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime?