# RestSharp POST request translation from cURL request

Tags: c#, .net, curl, jira, restsharp

I'm trying to make a POST request using RestSharp to create an issue in JIRA, and what I have to work with is an example that uses cURL. I'm not familiar with either enough to know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the [example](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Create+Issue) given in cURL:

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json"
http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Here's their example data:

```
{"fields":{"project":{"key":"TEST"},"summary":"REST ye merry gentlemen.","description":"Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API","issuetype":{"name":"Bug"}}}
```

And here's what I'm attempting with RestSharp:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "https://....";
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
....// connection is good, I use it to get issues from JIRA
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("issue", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("data", request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(issueToCreate));
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

What I get back is a 415 response of

```
Unsupported Media Type
```

Note: I also tried what was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400879/how-to-post-request-using-restsharp), but that did not resolve the issue. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont do

```
request.AddParameter("data", request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(issueToCreate));
```

instead try:

```
request.AddBody(issueToCreate);
```

Comment: Thank you, wal! For any others that find this post because it relates specifically to JIRA, I also discovered that Atlassian's REST service (and maybe this is across the board) is case-sensitive! In my JiraIssue class, I was creating properties like "Key" and "Summary" but it has to be "key" and "summary"...doh!

Comment: For anyone interested, I've implemented this RestSharp POST in a JIRA REST Client and WPF application [here](https://bitbucket.org/grodgers/jiravu/overview).

Answer (score 3):

A clean and more reliable solution you could use is described below:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://{URL}/rest/api/2");
var request = new RestRequest("issue/", Method.POST);

client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "pass");

var issue = new Issue
{
    fields =
        new Fields
        {
            description = "Issue Description",
            summary = "Issue Summary",
            project = new Project { key = "KEY" }, 
            issuetype = new IssueType { name = "ISSUE_TYPE_NAME" }
        }
};

request.AddJsonBody(issue);

var res = client.Execute<Issue>(request);

if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    Console.WriteLine("Issue: {0} successfully created", res.Data.key);
else
    Console.WriteLine(res.Content);
```

The full code I uploaded to gist: https://gist.github.com/gandarez/50040e2f94813d81a15a4baefba6ad4d

Jira documentation:
https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue