# Exception : ComponentActivator: could not proxy AsFactoryImplementation.<FactoryType>

Tags: .net, exception, castle-windsor, factory

I tried this code for implement the Factory in castle windsor, but it throws and exception as shown in title of this issue. i am following the examples of [Documentation here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx). plz point out where i am getting wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace AsFactoryImplementation
{
interface IDummyComponnentFactory
{
    IDummyComponnent creat();
    void Relese(IDummyComponnent factory);
}

interface IDummyComponnent
{
    void show();
}

class DummyComponnent:IDummyComponnent
{
    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("just testing this for better performance");
    }
}

class Program:WindsorContainer
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(Component.For<IDummyComponnent>().ImplementedBy<DummyComponnent>().Named("FirstConnection").LifeStyle.Transient
            ,Component.For<IDummyComponnentFactory>().AsFactory());

        var val = container.Resolve<IDummyComponnent>();
        val.show();

        var val2 = container.Resolve<IDummyComponnentFactory>();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isn't the inner exception explaining it well enough?

> Type `AsFactoryImplementation.IDummyComponnentFactory` is not visible to
>   DynamicProxy. Can not create proxy for types that are not accessible.
>   Make the type public, or internal and mark your assembly with
>   `[assembly:
>   InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]`
>   attribute.