# Big json file deserialization

Tags: c#, json, file, serialization

```
public void jsonLoad()
{
    StreamReader xD = new StreamReader("pobrane.txt");
    string costam = xD.ReadToEnd();
    xD.Close();
    Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(costam);
}
```

On last line of my code I am receiving the error 
`VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.`

My file that I want to open is big: 800KB, 37000 lines of code. Is there any way to skip  this limit?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968084/json-net-verificationexception-operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime

Comment: Look at the link keyboardP just gave - I think it might be your issue.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you using the NewtonSoft json library? Can you provide your json file?

Comment: What about light-weight parser generating small XML like objects (56B each) - made one by translating C++ version to C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372425/way-to-read-or-edit-big-json-from-to-stream